# How to connect with sql server database with Codeigniter?

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, webdriver, codeigniter-3

Help will be appreciated.

I am stuck and I am facing an error of Invalid DB driver Error. I had done research from my end. I had installed the driver of `sqlsvr` and add the extensions in `php.ini` file. I believe the driver is okay with the PHP version. [image]

`extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll` and
`extension=php_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll` in php.ini file.
Then I try to make a connection with Codeigniter Database.

$active_group = 'default';
    $query_builder = TRUE;

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'DESKTOP-Q52QI3K',
    'username' => 'noman',
    'password' => 'noman',
    'database' => 'TestDB',
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlsvr',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => TRUE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

I have this database on my local SQL server management tool. I am still facing the `Invalid DB driver` error.

Comment: the manual says to use the $config[‘dsn’] setting instead of ‘hostname’ and ‘database’, please read https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/connecting.html?highlight=pdo#manually-connecting-to-a-database. I'm not familiar with PDO driver setup.

Comment: I try that one also but still facing the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of research, I found an alternate solution. I would like to share it, in future may be it will help someone.

```
$serverName = "IP_Address";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DBName", "UID"=>"Username", "PWD"=>"Password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );
if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}else{
     echo "connected";
}
```

I use the custom php connection with sql database.